# C++ DLL Memory Reading Crashes

Tags: c++, memory, dll

I've been trying all day how to read properly the memory of a game with my injected DLL, it works correctly but if the DLL reach other type of variable which is not "float" then it crashes. My question is, how can I detect if is float and avoid crashes. Here is my code:

```
for (DWORD i = 0x1000000; i < 0x2FFFFFF; i += 0x4)
{
    DWORD Base = *(DWORD*)(base + i);
    DWORD lvl_2 = *(DWORD*)(Base + 0x8);
    float* posx = static_cast<float*>((float*)(lvl_2 + 0x90));

    Position_x = static_cast<float>(*posx);
    if (Position_x > 7.05f && Position_x < 7.20f) //test > 7.05f && test < 7.20f || i == 0x2217710
    {
        fprintf(file, "Pointer: 0x%x  Position x: %.2f \n", i, Position_x);
    }
}
```

This is a scanner I made to update pointer of a game knowing the structs offsets. This code works correctly if I use as condition i == 0x2217710, it returns the correct position x of the player. If I remove the condition it crashes due to the line Position_x = static_cast... is converting other type of variable in float which is illegal for some variables. How could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need the line Position_x = static_cast<float>(*posx);??

Comment: You don't need the cast on that line (`*posx` is already `float`).

Comment: wont this work ??  if(posx != NULL)  Position_x = *posx;  is it crashes here or afterwards, then , it could be memory you donot have acess to/memory corruption.You could check signal no..

Comment: How does it crash? What exactly is the exception code? It could be something to do with memory alignment, for example.

Comment: You scan a random block of memory, assume it contains a pointer, and dereference that pointer. You should only dereference if you are sure the memory contains a pointer.

Comment: @basav You probably mean `if (posx != NULL)`. But there are lots of pointer values that are not null and not valid - this code is full of undefined behaviour. (Necessarily, in the circumstances.)

Comment: @Alan: agreed.the generated core dump would be helpful.

Comment: If I use (posx != NULL) the game is still crashing, is there any special condition to make only pass if the variable is float? The problem is exactly when I try to USE *posx, for example: Position_x = *posx; this makes a crash on game.

Comment: Also I can't see any exception because I inject the DLL with extreme injector to the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm pretty sure the problem isn't that it crashes when you have a pointer that isn't to a float. All binary values 0 - 0xFFFFFFFF are generally valid as float values, but some are "special", such as "not a number" - but as long as you only compare the value, etc, it will work just fine to use such values too - will just come out as `false` in the comparison.

Your actual problem is that you are making a pointer from `base+i`, and then using the content at that location as another pointer - but if `base+i` does not hold a valid pointer {which is pretty much most 32- or 64-bit values in most systems}, then your next fetch will go wrong. Unfortunately, there is no trivial way to check if a memory address is valid or not. In Windows, you could possibly use [`__try`, `__except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx) to catch when you are trying to read an invalid memory address and "do something else".